# Crear un horario en java

Tags: java, jtable

Es sabido que es imposible (eso creo) combinar dos celdas de un jtable, hay alguna manera de simular que se combinan, o hay alguna otra clase, que permita hacer eso? necesito realizar un horario de clases en java, gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esto a ver si te sirve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856733/how-to-merge-cell-in-defaulttablemodel-jtable

Answer (score 0):

Puede intentar con una matriz de Jlabels, en donde cada label tiene la respectiva información y para dar la sensación de "combinar celdas" puede asignarles que tanto ocupan con un GridbagLayout, ya que el GridbagLayout divide en cuadrícula y al ubicar un componente le podemos decir en que posición de la cuadrícula queremos que se ubique y cuantos campos ocupe...
Espero le hubiera servido en algo xD